# How do I read a LaTeX dataset?

Tags: longtable

I want to access the data from a published article (Coetzee, Jenny, et al. "Depression and Post Traumatic Stress amongst female sex workers in Soweto, South Africa: A cross sectional, respondent driven sample." PLoS One 13.7 (2018): e0196759.). The data is posted as a pdf in what appears to be LaTeX code:
https://figshare.com/articles/journal_contribution/Depression_and_Post_Traumatic_Stress_amongst_female_sex_workers_in_Soweto_South_Africa_A_cross_sectional_respondent_driven_sample/6744632

I have never used LaTeX and have no idea where to begin. I have downloaded MikTex. I don't know what to do next. Could someone please help or direct me to a basic instruction page that would address this? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to me to be the silliest that I've ever seen of preserving data. Anyway, this not a LaTeX document. It's *part* of a LaTeX document. I hope that someone will provide more useful information than this.

Comment: This is clearly a mistake on the part of the authors or PLOS1. They have created a PDF document containing a badly formatted LaTeX long table. I'll add an answer showing how you can see the data, but this is surely a mistake.

Comment: Thank you, I also have never seen data shared this way. I may have to try contacting the authors for more information.

Comment: Actually I can't really put an answer since the table is terrible LaTeX, and would require a lot of work that is not really doable for someone who has never used LaTeX at all. You should really contact the authors or the journal for a version of the data in CSV form.

Comment: If you're proficient with a plain text (code) editor you could probably turn it into a `&` delimited text file by removing the rest of the LaTeX markup (i.e., stuff beginning with \ or delimited by `{...}` but leaving all the `&` symbols. Then it would be easy to import it into Excel using `&` as the delimiter.

Comment: you would do better to go to the full paper https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0196759&type=printable then cut and past the data from the tables

Comment: Thanks Alan, I'll try the plain text as suggested. Thanks David, but this is supplemental material that is not in the other tables in the paper.